# Xubuntu guest does not autoresize in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu

I have a xubuntu 17 as guest in a virtual box. I also installed the guest settings. But auto resizing the resolution does not work, even not when use the extra button in "menu/view/auto resize"

How can I fix that? Before when I had Ubuntu (unity) 16.04 installed as guest it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the guest settings didn't work correctly, because the kernel in the virtual box OS was newer than my host kernel.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was setting Machine>Settings>Display>Graphics Controller to VBoxSVGA.